# Can we set a SVG image in default tablayout icon?

Tags: android, svg, android-tablayout

Can we set a SVG image in default tablayout icon?

Comment: check this https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/

Answer (score 0):

You can convert **SVG** To **VectorDrawable**.
Then you will be use in tab layout icon.

```
android {

    defaultConfig { 
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

Convert SVG To Vector Drawables:

> Right click on your project file then,  New -> Vector Asset -> Asset
>   Studio -> Local file (SVG, PSD)